# dictionary from string in python for facebook ads api

Tags: python, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to get Facebook's insights data. the code below was running before but its starts breaking now.

**Code:**

```
async_job = {
    "id": "169817458353501",
    "report_run_id": "169817458353501",
}
results = []
for item in async_job:
    print(item, type(item), async_job)
    data = dict(item)
    results.append(data)
```

**Error:**

```
data = dict(item)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

**I have tried with the JSON module as well but seems still not working.**

```
import json    
async_job = {
    "id": "169817458353501",
    "report_run_id": "169817458353501",
}
results = []
for item in async_job:
    print(item, type(item), async_job)
    data = json.loads(item)
    results.append(data)
```

any leads will be helpful.

Comment: What is the output of `print(item, type(item), async_job)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the `dict` `keys`,

which are only one value on each itearation.

`dict` needs at least one key-value pair.

Maybe you wish to iterate over `dict` `items` (i.e key-value pairs):

```
async_job = {
    "id": "169817458353501",
    "report_run_id": "169817458353501",
}
results = []
for key, value in async_job.items():
    data = {key: value}
    results.append(data)
```

Alternativly you can use comprehension:

`results = [{key: value} for key, value in async_job.items()]`